# Setting property in .css() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello guys probably i'm having a problem on setting property

```
transform: rotate(30deg)
```

in my selector

```
$('.box1').css('left', x);
```

I dont know where to add this line, can I put a variable in degrees? Thanks guys. I hope you can help me out fixing this.

Comment: Please post more of your code

Comment: `$('.box1').css('transform', 'rotate(30deg)');` innit?

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
$('.box1').css({
    left: x,
    transform: 'rotate(30deg)'
});
```

Or:

```
$('.box1').css('left', x).css('transform', 'rotate(30deg)');
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/s28vs/).

Comment: by the way i would like to do this when i scroll my mouse http://jsfiddle.net/juzjs/

Comment: @user3012847 that should be asked as a different question. My answer here answers the question you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$('.box1').css('left', x).css('transform', 'rotate(30deg)')
```